# Ionic 5 / Angular active link ion-tab-button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an ion-tab display in my app.component.html like that :

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="home">
      <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Accueil</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="restaurants">
      <ion-icon name="storefront-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Restaurants</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="contact">
      <ion-icon name="people-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Contact</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

Each "tab" like restaurants is a page which have its self routing.
When i navigate to "/restaurant" the ion-tab is ative.
I have another page to show one restaurant, but when i navigate to this page, the tab linked with /restaurant is not active.

Did you have any idea to set /restaurant tab active ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the "one restaurant" page is a child route of the "/restaurant" route. Like:

```
// restaurants.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: RestaurantsPage
      },
      {
        path: 'restaurants/:name',
        component: SingleRestaurantPage
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

For reference, you can check this demo repository: https://github.com/servrox/demo-ionic-tab-routing